# How to build a string with a loop?

Tags: javascript, string, loops, do-while, prompt

```
var game = prompt('Do you want to play?');

var i = 0;
do {
  if (prompt === 'Yes');
  {
    var game2 = prompt('Enter your word.');
    var game3 = prompt('Do you want to play again?');
  }
  i++;
} while (game3 !== 'No');
{
  console.log(game3);
}

console.log("You're words are: " + game2);
```

How do I take all the words outputted from this loop and build a string with it?

Ex: if all my words are "basketball, football, racing"

I want them to come out outputted like --> basketball football racing

Comment: One way: create an array: `var words = [];`. Push each word into the array: `words.push(game2);`. Use join to print with spaces: `console.log(words.join(' '));`

Comment: Either `prompt` is a function or a string. It can't be both in the context you are using it

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps...

```js
var game = prompt('Do you want to play?');
var game2 = '';
var space = ' ';
var i = 0;
do {
  if (prompt === 'Yes');
  {
    game2 = game2 + space  + prompt('Enter your word.');
    var game3 = prompt('Do you want to play again?');
  }
  i++;
} while (game3 !== 'No');
{
  console.log(game3);
}

prompt("You're words are: " + game2);
```

Comment: Program never terminates if you cancel for first time.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a few things wrong with your code. You could use the [.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method if you put all of the responses into an array.

```
var game = prompt('Do you want to play?');

var i = 0;
var words = [];
do {
  // if (prompt === 'Yes'); // this isn't doing anything
  // {
    words.push(prompt('Enter your word.'));
    var game3 = prompt('Do you want to play again?');
  // }
  i++;
} while (game3 !== 'No');
{
  console.log(game3);
}

console.log("You're words are: " + words.join(' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```js
var words = [];

var i = 0;
do {
  var game = prompt('Do you want to play' + ((words && words.length) ? ' again' : '') + '? (type yes to continue else exit)');
  if(game && game.toLowerCase() === 'yes') {
    var word = prompt('Enter your word.');
    if(word) {
      words.push(word);
    }
  }
} while (game && game.toLowerCase() === 'yes');

if(words && words.length) {
  console.log("You're words are: " + words.join(', '));
} else {
  console.log("no words selected!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To what i understood from your question, This should Work.

```
var game = prompt('Do you want to play?');

var i = 0;
var game2="";
do {
  if (prompt === 'Yes');
  {
    game2 += " "+prompt('Enter your word.');
    var game3 = prompt('Do you want to play again?');
  }
  i++;
} while (game3 !== 'No');
console.log(game3);
console.log("You're words are: " + game2);
```

Basically, you are just concatenating dynamically.

Comment: Hey Neil, THANK YOU SOOO MUCH!!! Ive been looking for a way to do this for the longest. What I dont understnad is why do you put " " for var game2?

Comment: @MohammedFahad.. I am glad it worked. Pls accept it as answer if u think it is. And about `game2="" `. i am just making sure that game2 is an empty string everytime.

Comment: Why an empty string every time? I dont quite understand that

Comment: by everytime i mean, every time a person is asked "Do you want to play?" and not when "Do you want to play again?".
this is just initialization, if we dont do that , game2 will hold undefined.
And when we concatenate, we will get the output as :
"You're words are: undefinedbasketball football racing"

Answer (score 0):

You can go with String Array:

```
var gameArr =[];
gameArr.push(prompt('Do you want to play?'));

var i = 0;
do {
  if (prompt === 'Yes');
{
  gameArr.push(prompt('Enter your word.')); // This will append new string in current string.
  gameArr.push(prompt('Do you want to play again?'));// this also append the new string.
}
i++;
} while (game3 !== 'No');
{
  console.log(game3);
}

console.log("Your words are: " + gameArr[1]);
```

Let me know if you are unsure how you will get your responses from the array gameArr[].